# How can I set the width of Dialog in Material UI based on the changing content?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog, width, crop

I am creating a dialog with [MUI](https://material-ui.com/) which contains three types of content whose width is very different.

First, I need to upload an image and in the second content I need to crop it and third I have to be able to add a caption for it. So how do I set the width for the dialog such that even if images of varied dimensions are chosen it is completely shown?

Comment: i prefer to create my background and my window which i coutruct by js and css. Whne we use Mui component with own-making style, that means we are familiar with the most attributes of Mui style. I think mui tutorial and resources are not much enough... But Mui icons are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For that dialog, add `sx = {{ width:'fitContent' }}` and try if that works